# How to (RxJava) properly set conditions on which handler will process data, emitted from Observable?

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, rx-android

So, my task is to push my device's Location info, when it changes, to the remote server Json API service. If remote server is unavailable, my DatabaseManager must save them to a local database.

Here is my Retrofit API:

```
    public interface GpsService { 
        @POST("/v1/savelocationbatch") 
        SaveResponse saveLocationBatch(@Body LocationBatch locationBatch); 
    }

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(myBaseUrl)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();

    GpsService service = retrofit.create(GpsService.class);
```

And a POJO class:

```
    public class LocationBatch{

        @SerializedName("LocationPointList")
        ArrayList<LocationPoint> locationPointList;
        @SerializedName("ClientId")
        String clientId;
        @SerializedName("ClientSecret")
        String clientSecret;

        //setter & getter
    }
```

My LocationPoint model:

```
    @Table(name="LocationPoints", id = "_id")
    public class LocationPoint extends Model {

        @SerializedName("Latitude")
        @Column(name="latitude")
        public Double latitude;

        @SerializedName("Longitude")
        @Column(name="longitude")
        public Double longitude;

        @SerializedName("Altitude")
        @Column(name="altitude")
        public Double altitude;

        //... setters, getters etc
}
```

All of my last locations are stored in a **CurrentLocationHolder** singleton (for batch sending/saving to DB/emitting from Observable). It's setLocation() method updates currentLocation variable, then puts it to the locationBuffer, than checks the buffer's size, than if buffer's size exceeds my MAX_BUFFER_SIZE variable, it fires locationBufferChanged.onNext(with a copy of a locationBuffer as argument), then it clears locationBuffer...

```
    public class CurrentLocationHolder {

        private List<LocationPoint> locationBuffer = 
                            Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
        private LocationPoint currentLocation;
        private final PublishSubject<List<LocationPoint>> locationBufferFull = 
                            PublishSubject.create();

        public Observable<List<LocationPoint>> 
                            observeLocationBufferFull(boolean emitCurrentValue) {
                return emitCurrentValue ?
                    locationBufferFull.startWith(locationBuffer) :
                    locationBufferFull;
            }

        public void setLocation(LocationPoint point) {
            this.currentLocation = point;
            locationBuffer.add(point);
            if (locationBuffer.size() >= MAX_BUFFER_SIZE) {
                locationBufferChanged.onNext(new ArrayList<>(this.locationBuffer));
            }
            locationBuffer.clear();
        }
    }
```

And here is my DatabaseManager:

```
    public class DatabaseManager {    
        private Subscription locationBufferSubscription;
        private static DatabaseManager instance;    
        public static void InitInstance() {
            if (instance == null) 
                instance = new DatabaseManager();
            }
        }

        public void saveToDb(ArrayList<LocationPoint> locArray){
            ActiveAndroid.beginTransaction();
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < locArray.size(); i++) {
                    locArray.get(i).save();
                }
                ActiveAndroid.setTransactionSuccessful();
            } 
            finally {
                ActiveAndroid.endTransaction();
            }
        }
    }
```

**My application's main goal:**

To write all of the listened LocationPoints to the HTTP server through Retrofit. If a remote server will be suddenly down for some reason (or internet connection would lost), my app should seamlessly write new locationPoints to a local database. When the server (or internet) will be up, some mechanism should provide saved local data to Retrofit's call.

**So, my questions are:**

1. How to create an Rx-Observable object, which will emit List normally to a Retrofit service, but when server (or internet) goes down, it should provide unsaved LocationPoints to DatabaseManager.saveToDb() method?
2. How to catch internet connection or server "up" state? Is it a good idea to create some Observable, which will ping my remote server, and as result should emit some boolean value to it's subscribers? What is the best way to implement this behavior?
3. Is there a simple way to enqueue Retrofit calls with a locally saved data (from local DB), when internet connection (server) will become "up"?
4. How not to loose any of my LocationPoints on the server-side? (finally my client app must send all of them!
5. Am I doing something wrong? I am a newbie to Android, Java and
   particularly to RxJava...

Answer (score 0):

Interesting task! First of all: you don't need to create DB for storing such tiny info. Android has good place for storing any `Serializable` data.
So for saving locally data crate Model like:

```
public class MyLocation implements Serializable {

   @Nonnull
   private final String id;
   private final Location location;
   private final boolean isSynced;

   // constructor...
   // getters...
}
```

Singleton class:

```
public class UserPreferences {
    private static final String LOCATIONS = "locations";
    @Nonnull
    private final SharedPreferences preferences;
    @Nonnull
    private final Gson gson;
    private final PublishSubject<Object> locationRefresh = PublishSubject.create();

public void addLocation(MyLocation location) {
    final String json = preferences.getString(LOCATIONS, null);

    final Type type = new TypeToken<List<MyLocation>>() {
    }.getType();

    final List<MyLocation> list;
    if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(json)) {
        list = gson.fromJson(json, type);
    } else {
        list = new ArrayList<MyLocation>();
    }
    list.add(lication);

    final String newJson = gson.toJson(set);
    preferences.edit().putString(LOCATIONS, newJson).commit();
    locationRefresh.onNext(null);
}

private List<String> getLocations() {
    final String json = preferences.getString(LOCATIONS, null);

    final Type type = new TypeToken<List<MyLocation>>() {
    }.getType();

    final List<MyLocation> list = new ArrayList<MyLocation>();
    if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(json)) {
        list.addAll(gson.<List<MyLocation>>fromJson(json, type));
    }

    return list;
}

@Nonnull
public Observable<List<MyLocation>> getLocationsObservable() {
    return Observable
            .defer(new Func0<Observable<List<MyLocation>>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<List<MyLocation>> call() {
                    return Observable.just(getLocations())
                            .filter(Functions1.isNotNull());
                }
            })
            .compose(MoreOperators.<List<MyLocation>>refresh(locationRefresh));
}

// also You need to create getLocationsObservable() and getLocations() methods but only for not synced Locations.

}
```

Change:

```
public interface GpsService { 
    @POST("/v1/savelocationbatch") 
    Observable<SaveResponse> saveLocationBatch(@Body LocationBatch locationBatch); 
}
```

Now the most interesting...make it all works.
There is [extention](https://github.com/jacek-marchwicki/rx-java-extensions) for RxJava. It has a lot of "cool tools" (btw, `MoreOperators` in UserPref class from there), also it has something for handling retrofit errors.

So let assume that location saving suppose to happens, when Observable `saveLocationObservable` emit something. In that case your code looks like:

```
final Observable<ResponseOrError<SaveResponse>> responseOrErrorObservable = saveLocationObservable
        .flatMap(new Func1<MyLocation, Observable<ResponseOrError<SaveResponse>>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<ResponseOrError<SaveResponse>> call(MyLocation myLocation) {
                final LocationBatch locationBatch = LocationBatch.fromMyLocation(myLocation);  // some method to convert local location to requesr one
                return saveLocationBatch(locationBatch)
                        .observeOn(uiScheduler)
                        .subscribeOn(networkScheduler)
                        .compose(ResponseOrError.<SaveResponse>toResponseOrErrorObservable());
            }

        })
        .replay(1)
        .refCount();
final Observable<Throwable> error = responseOrErrorObservable
     .compose(ResponseOrError.<SaveResponse>onlyError())
     .withLatestFrom(saveLocationObservable, Functions2.<MyLocation>secondParam())
     .subscribe(new Action1<MyLocation>() {
            @Override
            public void call(MyLocation myLocation) {
                   // save location to UserPref with flag isSynced=flase
            }
        });
final Observable<UserInfoResponse> success = responseOrErrorObservable
     .compose(ResponseOrError.<SaveResponse>onlySuccess())
     .subscribe(new Action1<SaveResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void call(SaveResponse response) {
                // save location to UserPref with flag isSynced=true
            }
        });
```